# How to strip all text located to the left of the first number Python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to augment addresses.
An example string:

```
"Unit 3/45 main st, London"
```

Alternatively, I am trying to create addresses from dirty inputs by a customer, eg

```
"U 68 25 MARKET ST"
"52/225 Jamboree Ave Old Saints Retirement Village"
"Unit 9 13-15 Endeavour Street"
```

I want to split the string into columns of `UNIT NUMBER`, `STREET NUMBER`, `STREET NAME`, `TYPE`, `SUBURB` etc.

Comment: The best approach is to use an address validation web service. There are simply too many patterns to parse for

Comment: Do post the codes tried by you as well

Answer (score 0):

In response to how to strip all text to the left of the first number using python:

```
samp_string = "U 68 25 Market St"
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

def strip_left(string):
    length = len(string)
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,length):
        if (count == 0) and string[i] in numbers:
            split_string = string[i:length]
            count +=1
            return split_string
```

to get that returned string:

```
x = strip_left(samp_string)
print(x)
```

which outputs:

```
'68 25 Market St'
```

To pass an array of strings through:

```
import numpy as np

addresses = np.array(["U 68 25 MARKET ST",
"52/225 Jamboree Ave Old Saints Retirement Village",
"Unit 9 13-15 Endeavour Street"]) 

stripped = np.array([])

for j in range(3):
    stripped = np.append(stripped, strip_left(addresses[j]))
```

which will give you:

```
["68 25 MARKET ST", "52/225 Jamboree Ave Old Saints Retirement Village",
"9 13-15 Endeavour Street"]
```